# Need Optimized Python Solution for Leetcode 3Sum Question

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, optimization, compare-and-swap

Here's the Problem Statement:

```
Given an array nums of n integers, 
are there elements a, b, c in nums such  that a + b + c = 0? 
Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.
```

Note:

The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Example:

```
Given array nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4],

A solution set is:
[[-1, 0, 1],[-1, -1, 2]]
```

I'm solving Leetcode 3Sum problem right now and getting Time Limit Exceeded error for the below Code:

```
class Solution:
def threeSum(self, nums):
    triplets=[]
    nums.sort()
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        l=i+1
        r=len(nums)-1
        while l<r:
            sum=nums[i]+nums[l]+nums[r]
            if sum==0:
                if not [nums[i],nums[l],nums[r]] in triplets:
                    triplets+=[[nums[i],nums[l],nums[r]]]
            if sum<0:
                l+=1
            else:
                r-=1
    return triplets
```

Can anyone tell me where can I optimize this code?

Comment: Add exact problem definition in question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm looks optimal in general (slightly better complexity exists but approach perhaps is too complex for practical purposes).

But seems that searching of sublist in list is rather slow operation (probably linear for unsorted)

Use dictionary instead and extract triplets at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        nums.sort()
        result = []
        N = len(nums)
        for i in range(N):
            if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
                continue
            target = -nums[i]
            l = i + 1
            r = N - 1
            while l < r:
                if nums[l] + nums[r] == target:
                    result.append([nums[l],nums[r],nums[i]])
                    l = l + 1
                    while l <= r and nums[l] == nums[l - 1]:
                        l = l + 1
                elif nums[l] + nums[r] > target:
                    r = r - 1
                else:
                    l = l + 1
        return result
```